# Correct spacing for "Smith et al. (2008)"

Tags: academic-writing

An academic paper is referred to as using the authors name and publication year.

For example,

1. Smith (2008) studied the property of blah-blah
2. Smith and Johnson (2013)'s article investigated blah-blah
3. Johnson et al.(2009)'s paper studies blah-blah

Here I wonder what is the correct spacing between the name(s) and year (in the parenthesis) and between year and "'s".

In #1. putting a space between Smith and (2008) looks natural,
but in #2, it is weird because there is a space between Johnson and "'s".
(Without (2013), it becomes "Johnson 's")

Is there any clear rule or common practice for this?

Comment: Please note that a paper doesn't study anything. "In their study, Johnson and Smith (2013) found that ..."

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure, but with correct grammar, I'm fairly sure it would be this:

Smith and Johnson's (2013) article investigated blah-blah

Comment: That's basically correct, except that the article didn't investigate anything, Smith and Johnson did.

Comment: @what true; you might have to fudge the verb. *The article discussed* or *presented* or something.

Comment: I was just copying what the other answer said, but true.

Answer (score 1):

That's an annoying construction to punctuate, I agree. You might try:

> Smith and Johnson's article (2013) investigated blah blah
>
> The article from Smith and Johnson (2013) investigated blah blah
>
> The paper from Johnson et al. (2013) investigated blah blah

Please note the space between *al.* and *2013.* The *al.* is short for *alia,* meaning "others."

In any case, I wouldn't put the apostrophe-S after the year in parens. It looks too weird. Reword until you get the year and possessive apart.